# How to upload file to aws S3 from EC2 instance with private IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

Normally I can download and upload files to S3 instance using:

```
using (var fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(new AmazonS3Client(credentials, regionEndpoint)))
{
    await fileTransferUtility.UploadAsync(filePath, bucketName, directoryName);
}
```

It work's as expected from local computer and EC2 instances with public IP.
But when I launch instance only with private IP - only download works but on upload it throws an exception:

```
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.WebExceptionHandler.HandleException(IExecutionContext executionContext, WebException exception) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\ErrorHandler\_bcl\WebExceptionHandler.cs:line 44
    at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ExceptionHandler`1.Handle(IExecutionContext executionContext, Exception exception) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\ErrorHandler\ExceptionHandler.cs:line 38
    at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.ProcessException(IExecutionContext executionContext, Exception exception) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\ErrorHandler\ErrorHandler.cs:line 204
    at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__5`1.MoveNext() in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\ErrorHandler\ErrorHandler.cs:line 104
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__9`1.MoveNext() in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\CallbackHandler.cs:line 0
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CredentialsRetriever.<InvokeAsync>d__7`1.MoveNext() in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\CredentialsRetriever.cs:line 98
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__10`1.MoveNext() in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\RetryHandler\RetryHandler.cs:line 0
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__10`1.MoveNext() in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\RetryHandler\RetryHandler.cs:line 137
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__9`1.MoveNext() in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\CallbackHandler.cs:line 0
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__9`1.MoveNext() in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\CallbackHandler.cs:line 0
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Amazon.S3.Internal.AmazonS3ExceptionHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__1`1.MoveNext() in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Services\S3\Custom\Internal\AmazonS3ExceptionHandler.cs:line 62
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorCallbackHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__5`1.MoveNext() in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\ErrorCallbackHandler.cs:line 58
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.MetricsHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__1`1.MoveNext() in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\MetricsHandler.cs:line 0
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Amazon.S3.Transfer.Internal.SimpleUploadCommand.<ExecuteAsync>d__10.MoveNext() in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Services\S3\Custom\_bcl+coreclr+pcl\Transfer\Internal\_async\SimpleUploadCommand.async.cs:line 42
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
    at ..StorageService.<UploadFileAsync>d__13.MoveNext() in ..\StorageService.cs:line 100
```

What should I set up on S3 or while launching EC2 with private IP? Or I must always enable public IP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up [VPC Endpoint for Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-vpc-endpoint-for-amazon-s3/)

Comment: Or add a NAT Gateway to the VPC.